# React-redux application state is set before component is mounted

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that needs to know redux state when it mounts.  I have mapStateToProps set to be notified of state change, but the change happens before the component exists, so it never gets notified.  Is there any way to get notified of the redux state when it mounts?

Comment: what kind of notification do you want? if you mean `this.props`, then it should be there if you mapped it using `mapStateToProps`. maybe show some sample codes?

Comment: You're right! It is in props.  I was looking for componentWillReceiveProps to get fired, but of course it is already in props when the component mounts.  Thank you!  If you create an answer, I will check it.

Comment: Haha ok, I'll create an answer, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything you need is inside `this.props` via `mapStateToProps`! It'll be ready when `componentDidMount` fired so just grab and use it.